# Keycloak: input for user's password using <input type="text">

Tags: html, security, keycloak, jboss-tools

Keycloak is using `<input type="text">` in administration for setting user's password. They say it is ok because they are masking input value using a special font (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/5116) - because of password managers. I don't agree with that, because browser is still autocompleting already inserted values which is security vulnerability:

[image: screenshot]

What is the correct way how to fix it? I found there is attribute [autocomplete=off](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) for `<input>`. Is there any other solution?

Comment: So you can write `<input type="password">` and style again?

Comment: @TanDuong Sorry I don't understand your question. What do you mean by writing style again?

Comment: I mean you can use javascript to replace `type=text` to `type=password` and use css to make input the same style with the old one.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to do in githubs pullrequest but they rejected it. That§s why I'm asking about another solution

Comment: I think the only way to do is use `autocomplete=off` if they don't wanna change.

Answer (score 0):

You can natively change this to a masked input field by changing the type to `<input type=“password”>`. It's a good idea to turn off autocomplete off to prevent browsers from trying to guess input.

```
<input type=“password” autocomplete=off>
```

If you absolutely cannot use the password type, then you're going to need a custom type name  (not "text") for your input fields that are secret.

```
<input type="secretField">
```

Then add some css for this field type

```
input[type="secretField"]
{
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

Here is an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g69k0scu/).